# Adjusting the width of input field

Tags: javascript

I have basic javascript prompt() function

```
function askUser() {

if(confirm('Are you sure you want to add this item?')) {
   if(prompt('How many of this would you like to order?', '')) {
......
```

What i want to achieve is to ajust the width of the input field to maybe 30px when the prompt message pops up on screen? User will just have to input a numeric value or quantity of 2 integers.

And also how do i check if the entered values is integer? if not i'd like to alert the user that he enters an invalid value.

thank you.

Comment: Use a dialog instead of prompt

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to make a custom dialog you should use something like http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ . you cant really edit confirm();

to check if value is an integer you could use parseInt() or parseFloat()
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

or test if the input data only contains numbers: `inputData.match(/\d/)`

Comment: it is the width of input field from prompt() function that i want to adjust. Is that possible? because i am only interested with the valued entered by the user.